# Keras 'Error when checking input' when trying to predict multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras

I have a net with a length 4 input vector, length 2 output vector. I am trying to predict multiple inputs simultaneously. If I just want to predict one, I would do the following and it works:

```
in = numpy.array( [ [1,2,3,4] ] )
self.model.predict(in)
# prediction = [ [1,2] ]
```

However, when I try to pass in multiple inputs I get `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)`

```
in = numpy.array( [
[1,2,3,4],
[1,2,3,4]
]
)
#OR
in = numpy.array( [
[ [1,2,3,4] ],
[ [1,2,3,4] ]
]
)
self.model.predict(in)
#ERR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Code =

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))

    print(batch_arr[:,3][0])
    predictions = self.model.predict(batch_arr[:,3][0])
    print(predictions)
    print(batch_arr[:,3])
    predictions = model.predict(batch_arr[:,3])
```

Output =

```
[[-0.00441936 -0.20398824 -0.08134908  0.09739554]]
[[ 0.01860509 -0.01136071]]
[array([[-0.00441936, -0.20398824, -0.08134908,  0.09739554]])
 array([[-0.00517939,  0.38975933, -0.11951023, -0.9718224 ]])
 array([[0.00272119, 0.0025476 , 0.002645  , 0.03973542]])
 array([[-0.00421809, -0.01006362, -0.07795483, -0.16971247]])
 array([[-0.00904593,  0.19332681, -0.10655871, -0.64757587]])
 array([[ 0.00654432,  0.00347247, -0.15332555, -0.47302148]])
 array([[-0.01921821, -0.17354519, -0.20207744, -0.58569029]])
 array([[ 0.00661377,  0.20038962, -0.16278598, -0.80983334]])
 array([[-0.00348096,  0.18171964, -0.07072813, -0.38913168]])
 array([[-0.01268919, -0.00548544, -0.08286095, -0.27108632]])
 array([[ 0.01077598, -0.19254374, -0.004982  ,  0.33175341]])
 array([[-4.37101750e-04, -5.68196965e-01, -1.99532537e-01,
         1.10581883e-01]])
 array([[ 0.00657382, -0.19263146, -0.00402872,  0.33368607]])
 array([[ 0.00677398,  0.19760551, -0.00076944, -0.25153403]])
 array([[ 0.00261579,  0.19642629, -0.13894668, -0.71894379]])
 array([[-0.0221003 ,  0.37477368, -0.03765055, -0.63564477]])
 array([[-0.0110009 ,  0.37599703, -0.0574645 , -0.66318148]])
 array([[ 0.00277214,  0.19763152,  0.00343971, -0.25211181]])
 array([[-9.31810654e-05, -2.06245307e-01, -8.09019674e-02,
         1.47356796e-01]])
 array([[ 0.00709025, -0.37636771, -0.19725323, -0.11396513]])
 array([[ 0.00015344, -0.01233088, -0.07851076, -0.11956039]])
 array([[ 0.01077811, -0.18439307, -0.19043179, -0.34107231]])
 array([[-0.01460483,  0.18019651, -0.05036345, -0.35505252]])
 array([[-0.0127989 ,  0.19071515, -0.08828268, -0.58871071]])
 array([[ 0.01072609,  0.00249456, -0.00580012,  0.0409061 ]])
 array([[ 0.01062156,  0.00782762, -0.17898265, -0.57245695]])
 array([[-0.01180104, -0.37085843, -0.1973209 , -0.23782701]])
 array([[-0.00849912, -0.00780031, -0.07940117, -0.21980343]])
 array([[ 0.00672477,  0.00246062, -0.00160252,  0.04165408]])
 array([[-0.02268911, -0.36534914, -0.21379125, -0.36284594]])
 array([[-0.00865513, -0.20170279, -0.08379724,  0.0468145 ]])
 array([[-0.0256848 ,  0.17922475, -0.03098346, -0.33335449]])]
 #ERR
```

Edit: When I print out the shape of `batch_arr[:,3]` I get `(32,)`, not `(32,4)` as I expected. Thus I'm guess the numpy array does not know the shape of its inner arrays. Is there an easy way to fix that? It might be the root of the problem

Comment: Could you please post whole code

Comment: Are you sure this does not work: 
`input = numpy.array( [
[1,2,3,4],
[1,2,3,4]
]
)` and `model.predict(input)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the way that I had created my numpy array. I created it with indices of variable size, and thus it didn't know it was shaped (32,4), only that it was (32,). Reformulating the logic to ensure that the array is always a set width from the beginning allowed the array to be a (32,4), which allowed the prediction to work.